# grails acegi security constraints bypassed on forward

Tags: grails, spring-security

After googeling i found references that states that acegi security constraints isn't uphold upon forward.

I tested it in my application, and i can confirm that i suffer from this issue.

Does anyone know if the same issue is found in the recommended spring security plugin? If not, then it seems like it's time for me to start upgrading from acegi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security is implemented using Servlet filters, so doing a server-side forward won't be checked since no filters are involved. A redirect would work (although it might not be appropriate for this use case) since it will result in a new request.

Although this works the same in both the Acegi and Spring Security Core plugins (both wrap Spring Security) you should still upgrade - no more work is being done for the old plugin and the new one is actively maintained.

Comment: With the new spring security, is there service classes which allow me to programmatically do the necessary security checks?